# twig for latex file

Tags: symfony, twig, latex

I would like to know how to add data from the database into a latex file in Symfony.

My Latex file

```
\begin{flushleft}
{% for occasion in occasions %}
{{ occasion.nom }}
Description de l'occasion
\end {flushleft}
\begin{question}{somme}
{% for competence in occasion.competences %} 
{{ competence.nom }} : {{ competence.description }}
competence nom et description
\AMCOpen{lines=3}{\wrongchoice[E]{E}\scoring{0}\wrongchoice[M]{m}\scoring{1}\wrongchoice[A]{a}\scoring{2}\correctchoice[N]{n}\scoring{3}}
\end{question}
\begin{flushleft}
  {% for sousCompetences in competence.sousCompetences %}
  {{ sousCompetences.description  }} 
Description de la competence
  {% endfor %}
\end {flushleft}
{% endfor %}
{% endfor %}

% \AMCaddpagesto{3} 

}
```

I tried to export the data via twig but I do not see how to do it.
This my controller

```
public function ficheCompetencesAction(Request $request)
    {

        if($request->isXmlHttpRequest()){

            $req=$request->request->get('fiche_occasion');
            $ue=$req['ues'];
            return new JsonResponse($ue);
        }

        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $form = $this->createForm( FicheOccasion::class );
        $form->handleRequest( $request );

        if( $form->isValid() )
        {
            $req=$request->request->get('fiche_occasion');
            $etudiant=$em->getRepository(Utilisateur::class)->find($req['etudiants']);

            $ueSelected=$req['ues'];
            if($ueSelected!='')
            {
                //on recupere les données du formulaires
                $ue=$em->getRepository(UE::class)->find($ueSelected);

                //on recupere les occasions correspondante
                $occasions=$ue->getOccasions();

                //on genere le twig desiré
                $html = $this->renderView('PolytechSkillsBundle:Admin/Rapport/Rapport:fichesPDF.tex.twig',
                    ['user'=>$etudiant,
                        'occasions'=>$occasions,
                        'ue'=> $ue,
                        'QrCodeNumeroEtu' => $etudiant->getNumero()
                    ]);
                //servira a generer le pdf à partir du twig
                return new Response(
                    $this->get('knp_snappy.pdf')->getOutputFromHtml($html),
                    200,
                    array(
                        'Content-Type'          => 'application/pdf',
                        'Content-Disposition'   => 'attachment; filename="test.pdf"'

                    )
                );
            }
        }

        return $this->render( 'PolytechSkillsBundle:Admin/Rapport/Rapport:fiches.html.twig',[ 'form' => $form->createView()] );
    }
```

I want to create the FichesPDF.tex.twig file from the data sent but the problem it sends me a result with the latex tags in it (it considers them as text)

Comment: What data to put where? Be more specific. What's the code that you have tried?

Comment: I have tried nothing because I do not see how to do it but what I want to do is write information that I retrieve from the database (such as the user name) in an .tex file

Comment: Open the file. Read the file. Modify it's content. Write it back to file. Close the file. Again, if you expect more specific help, you need to be more specific about your expected result.